# Controlling $L^p$-norm by $L^1$ and $L^\infty$ norms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I'm currently reading a proof of Bernstein's inequality for spectrally localised functions. One step in this proof is the claim that
$$\|\partial^\alpha g\|_p \leq \|\partial^\alpha g\|_1 + \|\partial^\alpha g\|_\infty$$
where the relevant norms are the $L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$ norms. In case it matters, $g$ is the fourier transform of a smooth, compactly supported function that is $1$ on the unit ball.

The obvious way of controlling the $L^p$ norm using the quantities on the right hand side (control the parts of the function above $1$ by the $L^\infty$ norm and the rest by the $L^1$ norm) doesn't yield anything useful but I don't see any strong improvements. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of Hoelder inequality and [Young inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products)
($ab\le \frac1pa^p+\frac1qb^q$ for $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$)
$$
\|u\|_{L^q}^q = \int |u|^q dx \le \|u\|_{L^\infty}^{q-1} \|u\|_{L^1}
\le \frac{q-1}q \|u\|_{L^\infty}^{q}+ \frac1q\|u\|_{L^q}^q,
$$
then
$$
\frac{q-1}q \|u\|_{L^\infty}^{q}+ \frac1q\|u\|_{L^q}^q \le \|u\|_{L^\infty}^{q}+ \|u\|_{L^q}^q \le (|u\|_{L^\infty}+ \|u\|_{L^q})^q
$$